# Sourcetree and git bash go out of sync?

Tags: git, git-bash, atlassian-sourcetree, git-rebase

My understanding is that `Sourcetree` and `Git Bash` are just UI (view) looking at the same model (git repo status).  So they should show the same state (after I refresh, that is).

But I just did a `rebase -i` through SourceTree, and perhaps some wrong operations, now I have the two UI reporting different states:

1. Sourcetree (and Eclise Egit, too) thought my repo is clean and I could even checkout different branches at will
2. Git Bash thought I am still in the middle of an interactive rebase and show the state as (where `foo` is a certain branch)

   (foo|REBASE-i 1/1)

When I did `rebase --continue` in Git Bash, I got these errors:

```
$ git rebase --continue
error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/heads/foo': cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/foo': is at 70b13393524028fbeb15b853b3d058f6802f961b but expected 827b12fb1ddb5599e744d0bc07ec831d1ef0c843
error: could not update refs/heads/foo
```

How can this be possible?

How can I bail out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am providing my own answer here.

For the same error (but maybe different causes), there is a popular way to solve the problem by running

```
git gc --prunce=now
```

See this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38272660/1168041)

But this did not solve my problem.

Finally, I power-cycled my machine and then ran

```
git rebase --abort
```

And then the problem went away.  I think what happened was that there were some dead process hold on to some file-system object and that prevented the `git rebase --abort` from working correctly before the power cycle.

However, at the end I still do not understand why Sourcetree (and Eclipse/Egit and Git GUI) would report a different state from `Git bash` (apparently it was the latter who was reporting a wrong state).