# Build failing with error : cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/users/bill.roper/develop': is at b10165 but expected 5f

Tags: git, jenkins, github, gitlab

Jenkins build is failing with error below error. Kindly help to fix it.

> git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
>   using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
>   Setting http proxy: www-proxy.us.oracle.com:80
>   git fetch --tags --force --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 1:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: From https://alm.oraclecorp.com/epm/s/epm_pbcs_15318/scm/strategicmodeling
>    * [new branch]          users/aaron.weber/mydevelop -> origin/users/aaron.weber/mydevelop
>    * [new branch]          users/abhilash.mund/mydevelop -> origin/users/abhilash.mund/mydevelop
>   error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/users/bill.roper/develop': is at cf9f03f3568e8e7b60918a8fc6e39a3d8d265c42 but expected 5baac24b91a27586748ad1afb6e8142ed7bf568f
>    ! 5baac24b9..02c773ae0  users/bill.roper/develop -> origin/users/bill.roper/develop  (unable to update local ref)
>    * [new branch]          users/dave.farr/develop -> origin/users/dave.farr/develop

We started deleting the branches and recreating them again with different name and only with small chars. this is working but we are facing issues when owners of branch are not available to do this. Will different user renaming the branch remotely causes any issues like loosing the uncommitted changes of branch owner. Or f there is any other solution please let me know

We want the jenkins build to be successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in terminal

"cd /.git/refs/remotes/origin"

do "ls", you will see some branches and HEAD

Remove the branch you think has the problem

"rm branchname"

If it did not work, delete all branches/HEAD

you may wana pull

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6656619/6309), try in your Jenkins job first a:

```
git gc --prune=now
git remote prune origin
```

The second command will remove references to remote (since deleted) branches in the namespace origin.

Something like:

```
stage('Checkout') {
    // Update our shared reference repo for all branches/PRs
    dir('..') {
        if (fileExists('yourRepo.git')) {
            dir('yourRepo.git') {
            sh 'git --prune=now'
            sh 'git remote prune origin' // update the clone
            sh 'git prune' // prune to avoid "warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects"
            }
        } else {
            sh 'git clone --mirror /url/to/yourRepo.git' // create a mirror
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A more targeted approach: `git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/users/bill.roper/develop/`

Comment: I am getting error as  $ git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/users/bill.roper/develop/
error: refusing to update ref with bad name 'refs/remotes/origin/users/bill.roper/develop/'

Comment: @jon And the other commands? Would they be enough to make your problem go away?

Comment: Could you please tell me where to add the other commands in this jenkins pipeline script :--  env.EPBCSMODULES_BRANCH_NAME="develop"
 def downloadLocationForEPBCS="epmpbcs-release-local/Platform/EPBCSModules/${EPBCSMODULES_BRANCH_NAME}/latest"

 
  if ("${BRANCH_NAME}"=="develop")
  {
   properties(
   [
    pipelineTriggers([cron('H 4 * * 2,4')]),
   ]
   )
  }
  else
  {
   properties(
   [
    pipelineTriggers([cron('')]),
   ]
   )
  }


  stage('Checkout') 
  {
    
   scmVars = checkout scm
  }

Comment: @jon Sure: I have edited the answer to add an example, modeled after https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/57a418f653c4394666dc472f5de6666fd16e1504/Jenkinsfile#L133-L145

Comment: the build is failing at very beginnig stage  > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stde

Comment: @jon Can you edit your question with the full error message?

Comment: I have edited the question. Build is successful after deleting the error branch. But the problem is we can't keep on ask developers to delete their branches

Comment: @jon Then another approach would be to use a dedicated Git repo (dedicated to be used only by Jenkins), where Jenkins would start by fetching from your dev repo only the branch to build, ignoring any other problematic branch.

Comment: But this is a multi branch pipeline job. is there any way to use only the branch to build

Comment: @jon Yes, by monitoring the original repo as you do right now, but by fetching only the branch you need to the dedicated repo, and triggering a dedicated job on that branch of that dedicated repository.

Comment: I am using scripted pipeline. could you please tell me how to do that