# While executing "git fetch origin" getting below error

Tags: git

While I am executing `git fetch origin` I am getting this error how do I resolve this:

```
$ git fetch origin
From https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/xxxx/_git/xxxx
   e32d933c7f..5f190a8989  test_Aut  -> origin/test_Aut
   10ef19a741..bf327cd495  test_master -> origin/test_master
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/test_Aut': is at 5f190a898916a1539a28381d4bdaaa2ba30ee1e4 but expected e32d933c7f55f239a255ad172e0280519396ba22
 ! e32d933c7f..8ea9812b50  test_Aut  -> origin/test_Aut  (unable to update local ref)
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/test_master': is at bf327cd495cd95592983368ec2c846b4fd036539 but expected 10ef19a741c42c470fab13a63352c9fc13f25f22
 ! 10ef19a741...2c31863658 test_master -> origin/test_master  (unable to update local ref)
```

Thanks,
Samson

Comment: test_Aut is this exists in origin/remote

Comment: Please show the output from `git branch -a` as well.

Comment: `git branch -av` could also be useful to check local-remote associations.

Comment: Try the answers here: [Git and nasty "error: cannot lock existing info/refs fatal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656619/git-and-nasty-error-cannot-lock-existing-info-refs-fatal)