# detaching a subdirectory of a repo and making it a branch of  another repo?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I've a git repo, say repoA, with many subdirs. How can I detach one of the sub-directories, say dir1, and add it to another repo as a separate branch (with history)?

Secondly, how can I remove the history of the detached subdir from the repoA?

Comment: There's a tool called [`git-subtree`](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) that can split a subdir off from your repo. I don't know if it can remove the history of that subdir from your main repo though. If not, you can always do so with `git filter-branch`, though that command is a bit complex.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I've detached the sub-directory already with:
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter dir1 --prune-empty

That leaves me only with the dir1, now I have to add this directory to another repo, say RepoB, as a separate branch. The tricky part for me is this that how can I make the history of dir1 a part of the history of repoB, so whenever a user do a git clone of repoB, he can see the whole history of dir1 as well.  When searching for a solution I came to know about 'graft' file, and git-rebase. But, as I've mentioned I am new to git, I've no idea how to use these options.

Comment: So you have a repo that contains only the history of `dir1`. The simplest thing to do is use `git fetch` to fetch this history into the repo you want to add it to, and then just `git merge` it in.

Answer (score 1):

#### First part of the question:

> How can I detach one of the sub-directories, say dir1, and add it to another repo as a separate branch (with history)?

```
git checkout -b tempBranch
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter dir1 --prune-empty
```

In a second repository:

```
git remote add filtered_dir1 ../original_repo
git fetch filtered_dir1
git merge filtered_dir1/tempBranch
```

---

#### Second part of the question:

> Secondly, how can I remove the history of the detached subdir from the repoA?

$ git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -r -f --cached --ignore-unmatch dir1" --prune-empty

This might fail with a warning about being unable to make a backup; I'm not sure what this is about, but adding `-f` will force `git-filter-branch` to run anyway.

This will run in the **current branch only**. If you want to run it on **all branches**, append `-- --all`. Note the `-- --all`.

**Some notes:**

1. When running `git filter-branch`, you will filter the branch you're on. (Rather obviously, if you think about it). If you're trying to extract some history to push into a second repository, you probably want to `git filter-branch` on a **new branch**, so that the original repository doesn't lose anything.
2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982055/detach-many-subdirectories-into-a-new-separate-git-repository) has some useful information in it.
3. `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` will make `subdirectory` the new root directory of the branch - it will move files from `subdirectory` to `/`. To fix this, there's an example at the bottom of the `EXAMPLES` section from `man git-filter-branch`:

   > To move the whole tree into a subdirectory, or remove it from there:

   ```
      git filter-branch --index-filter \
              'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&newsubdir/-" |
                      GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
                              git update-index --index-info &&
               mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
   ```