# git subtree changes the package directory

Tags: git, version-control, git-subtree

I'm using git subtree to split specific package of a java project into another repository (retaining the history) as the following

```
$ git subtree split -P src/main/java/com/company/package -b moved_package_branch
```

then when switch to this branch I find that all the content of the package is moved to the root of the project not to it original place (src/main/java/com/company/package)

Any idea about how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used another git command than subtree as the following

```
$ git checkout -b moved_package_branch
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached -qr -- . && git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT -- src/main/java/com/company/package' --prune-empty
```

Note that you can include multiple folders (space separated)

Reference:
last answer from @David Smiley

[Detach many subdirectories into a new, separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982055/detach-many-subdirectories-into-a-new-separate-git-repository)