# Git subtree and multiple directories

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a rather large git repository that has a directory where I maintain library code. The directory contains a number of subdirectories.

```
repo
+--- lib
|    +--- A
|    +--- B
...
|    +--- Z
```

Now let us assume that I want to open source subdirectories `A,...,M` and keep subdirectories `N,...,Z` close sourced. Let us also assume that I would like to:

- Keep `A,...,M` in a single open source repository. The reason for this is that the directories `A,...,M` have interdependencies and it would be confusing to split them into individual repositories.
- Keep the structure of my closed source repository intact. For example, I could create subdirectories `lib/pub` and `lib/pvt`, but this would have cascading effects requiring changing references elsewhere or would require a lot of symlinks (`lib/A -> lib/pub/A`).
- Have a solution akin to `git subtree` where I can modify code either in my closed source repository or in the open source one and I can easily sync the changes between the two repositories.

I have searched for a solution in both stackoverflow and google, but there does not seem to be an obvious one. Conceptually this is something that `git subtree` should be able to do, but it only works with a single subdirectory.

I have looked into the `git-subtree` script with the intent of modifying it.

> https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh

It appears to me that if I was to modify `subtree_for_commit()` I should be able to convince `git subtree split` to consider more than a single directory for splitting. But my knowledge of git is not enough to understand what the script is doing and modify it without breaking things.

If you have any solution for the above mentioned problem or any other pointers in modifying `git-subtree`, please let me know.

Comment: I'm encountering the same desire, since my subdirectories A,B,C are all inter-related, and I want to split them away from subdirectories D,E,F.

Might have to use filter-branch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detach many subdirectories into a new, separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982055/detach-many-subdirectories-into-a-new-separate-git-repository)

Answer (score 5):

### Splitting a subtree mixed with files from the parent project

This seems to be a common request, however I don't think there's a ***simple*** answer, when the folders are mixed together like that.

The general method I suggest to split out the library mixed in with other folders is this:

1. Make a branch with the new root for the library directories:

   ```
   git subtree split -P lib/ -b temp-br
   git checkout temp-br
   ```
2. Then use something to re-write history to remove the parts that aren't part of the library. I'm not expert on this but I was able to experiment and found something like this to work:

   ```
   git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z' HEAD
   ```

   Note: You might need to delete the back-up made by filter-branch if you make successive commands.

   ```
   git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/temp-br
   ```
3. Lastly, just create a new repo for the library and pull in everything that's left:

   ```
   cd <new-lib-repo>
   git init
   git pull <original-repo> temp-br
   ```

Comment: Does this answer even relate to the question asked?  He wants to git-subtree-split multiple subdirectories into a separate repo...

Comment: @enorl76 I think it does. filter-branch will remove the directories that are not needed in the new repo.

Comment: When you do the filter-branch, it tries to backup what you had in a new branch since the command is destructive. If you run the command again, to filter additional stuff out in steps, it would try to backup again, and since there's already a backup it would complain. If you know what you're already taking care to keep an original branch you can ignore the precaution and update-ref will remove backup branch.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `git subtree add`

See [Git subtree split two directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574407/git-subtree-split-two-directories), I think you may use that technique for more than two directories, even for multiple repos, i.e.

```sh
cd /repos/big-repo

# split out A..M branches
for N in {A..M}; do
  git subtree split --prefix=lib/$N --branch=split-$N
done

# create new repo
mkdir /repos/am-repo
cd /repos/am-repo
git init

# commit something or git-subtree add will complain and fail
touch .gitignore; git add .; git commit -m "begin history revision"

# split-in A..M branches
for N in {A..M}; do
  git subtree add --prefix=lib/$N ../big-repo split-$N
done
```

Comment: This doesn't act like keeping A through M as single repository that was split out. If a commit touches both A and M then the commit is duplicated in the split-A and split-M branches where it would be desirable to have a single commit that contains both A and M changes.

Comment: do i need to do a `git filter-branch` after the git subtree add?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shell script based on `git subtree`, it is much faster than solutions which are based on `git filter-branch --tree-filter`; its side effect is several extra `git mv` and `git merge` commits will be generated and added to final `HEAD`. If you feel ok of these extra empty commits, you can try:

```
ids=0
lists=(\
    "a/b" \
    "c/d/e" \
)
# subtree each path
for dir in ${lists[@]}
do
    echo git subtree split -P $dir -b split_dir_$ids
    git subtree split -P $dir -b split_dir_$ids
    ((ids++))
done

# restore folder structure
for (( idx=0; idx < ${#lists[@]}; idx++ ))
do
    git checkout split_dir_$idx
    dir=${lists[$idx]}
    mkdir -p $dir
    dirPrefix=${$dir%%/*}
    find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name $dirPrefix -and ! -name '\.*' \
        -exec git mv {} $dir \;
done

# merge
git checkout split_dir_0
for (( idx=1; idx < ${#lists[@]}; idx++ ))
do
    git merge -q split_dir_$idx
done

git push -u `target remote` `target branch`
```

Comment: will it work two way commit?

Answer (score -1):

When you have both subdirectories and files in a directory src you want to split into a separate repository that later becomes a submodule, there were not many answers.  Suppose you want dir2 and file2 moved to a new repo srcpublic then in the original repo,

git mv src/file2 src/dir2; git subtree split -P dir2 -b branch_dir2

In the new repo,
    subtree pull /dir2 branch_dir2;
    git mv dir2/file2 ../

New repo:
srcpublic - file2, dir2

Original repo:
src - file1, file2,
  dir1, dir2

When there are dozens of folders and files, it helps to put the commands in a script.