# Git subtree split two directories

Tags: git, git-subtree

I've been following [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864475/759866) to extract a subdirectory of my git repository into its own repository, while retaining the complete history.

My repository looks like:

```
src/
    http/
    math/
tests/
    http/
    math/
```

I want to create a new branch that only contains the  `src/math` and `tests/math` directories.

If I run the following command:

```
git subtree split -P src/math -b math
```

It creates a branch that contains the contents of the `src/math` directory, but discards the `src/math/` prefix.

If I try the same command with two directories:

```
git subtree split -P src/math -P tests/math -b math
```

It only extracts the contents of `tests/math`, ignoring `src/math`, and also discarding the `tests/math` prefix.

To summarize, I would like my final repository to look like:

```
src/
    math/
tests/
    math/
```

That is, keeping the original directory structure but discarding everything that's not explicitly mentioned in the command-line.

How can I do that?

Comment: I guess Downvoter did not understand the question.

Comment: this is not exactly a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982055/detach-many-subdirectories-into-a-new-separate-git-repository but it does ask for the same result. It's just that here the question is specific to `git subtree split`. I followed the procedure in the first answer and it works like a charm

Comment: It's a bit more work, but could you preserve history by moving each of the subdirectories to a new directory and then splitting that new common parent directory? You would have the extra commit from moving the files, but is that such a bad thing? No changes to prior commit hashes...

Comment: @cowboydan: Does `git subtree` maintain the rename history from outside of that directory? I’m not certain, though I know that e.g. `git filter-branch` doesn’t. If not, that would effectively cause this to eliminate the history.

Comment: @cowboydan: FYI: I just confirmed that `git subtree split` does _not_ maintain the rename history from outside of that directory, so this approach would be as effective as just copying the files to a new repository. It’s also worth noting that `git subtree split` itself rewrites your history, generating new hashes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detach many subdirectories into a new, separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982055/detach-many-subdirectories-into-a-new-separate-git-repository)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your needs you might get away with `git filter-branch`.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you merely want to have a repository with two directories removed (in the history?) this is probably your best shot.

See also [Rewriting Git History](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf tests/http src/http' --prune-empty HEAD
```

This will look into each commit and remove the two directories from this commit.
Be aware that this rewrites history (i.e.: alters your commit sha) and will cause headaches if you have a common history with another repository.

Comment: Actually, my example was an oversimplification, and I have many more folders than just `http` and `math`. Is there a way I can just specify which ones to keep, and not which ones to delete?

Comment: in essence you can put a bash script in there. can `rm` deal with what you'd like to keep -> nope. can bash do, yes. try to figure out how to use `find` to match your requirements. http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html

Comment: furthermore you can use regular expressions to match your directories. it's **simpler** and **faster** to tell `rm` what to delete.

Comment: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing this might also be helpful to have more powerful file globbing in bash.

Comment: I tried your solution by listing all the directories I want to delete. While it works fine, it keeps all the commits in the history, most of them being empty (no modified files). So it's very different from `git subtree split`, and unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for!

Comment: have you tried to read the manual of `git filter-branch` ? There is a `--prune-empty` to get rid of those commits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324799/git-remove-commits-with-empty-changeset-using-filter-branch also related SO question.

Comment: I've tried `--prune-empty`, which does 90% of the job, but there are still some unrelated commits left: those which were only deleting files outside of the relevant directories!

Comment: you could use `git rebase --interactive` and drop the 10%. I suppose this is a one time thing anyway.

Comment: Seems possible to achieve this without destroying history. See `git-subtree add`

Answer (score 9):

## Use `git-subtree add` to *split-in*

```sh
# First create two *split-out* branches
cd /repos/repo-to-split
git subtree split --prefix=src/math --branch=math-src
git subtree split --prefix=test/math --branch=math-test

# Now create the new repo
mkdir /repos/math
cd /repos/math
git init

# This approach has a gotcha:
# You must commit something so "revision history begins",
# or `git subtree add` will complain about.
# In this example, an empty `.gitignore` is commited.
touch .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "add empty .gitignore to allow using git-subtree"

# Finally, *split-in* the two branches
git subtree add --prefix=src/math ../repo-to-split math-src
git subtree add --prefix=test/math ../repo-to-split math-test
```

It worked for me with **`git --version` 2.23.0**. Also note that you can setup different prefixes at *split-in* time, i.e. add the `src/math/` to `src/` and `test/math/` to `test/`.

**Side note**: use `git log` at the new repo before commiting to a remote, to see if resultant history is ok enought for you. In my case I have some commits with duplicated messages, because my repo history was so dirty, but it's ok for me.

[Source](https://hans-hermann-bode.de/node/83)

Comment: You will get duplicates no matter how clean your commit history is because each time you call `git subtree split` it is rewriting your commit history for that branch. In this example, if you had ten commits that touched both `src/math` _and_ `test/math`, those will now become _twenty_ commits. Worse, each of those commits will, of course, be limited to modifications in one folder. That’s why it’s desirable instead to use something like `git filter-branch` (or, better yet, the third-party `git filter-repo`) so that you can include multiple folders in a single rewrite operation.

Comment: If you don't care about duplicate commit history as @JeremyCaney pointed out above, this is by far, the simplest correct answer.

Comment: This is the best answer for me. Other approaches are less intuitive, or inefficient.

Answer (score 7):

Use [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)
This is not part of git as of version 2.25. 
This requires Python3 (>=3.5) and git 2.22.0

```
git filter-repo --path src/math --path tests/math
```

For my repo that contained ~12000 commits *git-filter-branch* took more than 24 hours and *git-filter-repo* took less than a minute.

Answer (score 0):

To expand @laconbass answer

Initialize example git repository

```
mkdir repos
mkdir repos/repo-to-split || mkdir repos\repo-to-split
cd repos/repo-to-split || cd repos\repo-to-split
git init

mkdir src
mkdir src/math1 || mkdir src\math1
mkdir test
mkdir test/math2 || mkdir test\math2

echo "base readme" >> readme.md
echo "src/math1 readme" >> src/math1/readme.md || echo "src/math1 readme" >> src\math1\readme.md
echo "test/math2 readme" >> test/math2/readme.md || echo "test/math2 readme" >> test\math2\readme.md

git add .
git commit -m "readme's added"
```

You need to

1. Make sure there are no changes:

```
git add . && git stash
```

2. "git subtree split branch" a directory from master/main into its own branch

```
# Prefer directories in branch names like features/[feature name]
git subtree split --prefix=src/math1 --branch=math/src
git subtree split --prefix=test/math2 --branch=math/test
```

3. delete the directory you just created a branch for

```
# On windows, when you install git, select option to add unix utilities to PATH for rm
rm -rf src/math
rm -rf test/math

git add .
git commit -m "temporarily remove git subtree split folder branches (adding back in next step)"
```

4. "git subtree add" the branch back into master/main

```
# Finally, *split-in* the two branches back into master
git subtree add --prefix=src/math1 ../repo-to-split math/src
git subtree add --prefix=test/math2 ../repo-to-split math/test

git add .
git commit -m "added git subtree split features back in"
```

Git subtree will keep a full copy of the branch in master/main

If you need to git subtree add to other remote/external repositories, that works too

Then I highly recommend creating hooks so git subtree push tries to push to the remote. Would be nice if permission failures while git subtree push would display as warnings and skip

Bonus:

```
cd ../../repos || cd ..\..\repos
git clone --bare repo-to-split repo-to-split-worktree
cd repo-to-split-worktree

git worktree add master
git worktree add math/src
git worktree add math/test

ls master || dir master
la math || dir math
```

You now have all branches in a single repository. You can navigate into each branch/trunk added and work like normal. While having access to other branches without needing to re-clone

Comment: above example should run on windows, mac, & linux

Comment: I currently have no idea how to be inside a "git subtree split feature" branch and push changes to master/main - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77187985/how-do-i-push-changes-from-within-a-branch-created-from-git-subtree-split-back-t :-(