# How do I push changes from within a branch created from git subtree split back to master?

Tags: git, version-control

### How do I push changes from within a branch created from git subtree split back to master?

Steps/example of how I create a git subtree split here here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77185189/458321

**Note:**

I know how to pull changes from the subtree split branch while in master/main
I know how to push changes while in master/main to the subtree split branch

I want to know how to push and pull changes while within the subtree split branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I did not find a way to:

- pushing changes from subtree split Branch (`math/src`) to `master`/`main` without switching branches

  I would still have to [switch branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309):

  ```bash
  git format-patch HEAD~1..HEAD
  git switch master
  git apply --cached <patch-file> --directory=src/math1/
  git commit -m "Applied changes from math/src to master"
  git switch math/src
  ```
- pulling changes from `master`/`main` to subtree split branch (`math/src`) without switching branches

  I would still have to switch branch:

  ```bash
  git switch master
  git format-patch -k --stdout HEAD~1..HEAD -- src/math1/ > master-changes.patch
  git switch math/src
  git am < master-changes.patch
  ```

That is why I would instead use [multiple worktrees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309), with [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)

That way:

- I do not switch inside my `math/src` checked out subtree
- I still can apply worm from/to `master` using the separate worktree folder, outside the subtree.

First: `git worktree add <path-to-new-worktree> master`

Then:

- pushing changes from subtree split Branch (`math/src`) to `master`/`main` without switching branches

  No more patch to do!

  ```bash
  git add .
  git commit -m "Changes in math/src"
  cd <path-to-new-worktree>
  git subtree merge --prefix=src/math1 math/src
  git add .
  git commit -m "Merged changes from math/src to master"
  git push origin master
  ```
- pulling changes from `master`/`main` to subtree split branch (`math/src`) without switching branches

  Again, no more patch.

  ```bash
  cd <path-to-new-worktree>
  git add .
  git commit -m "Changes in master"
  cd <path-to-original-worktree>
  git merge master
  # or
  git rebase master
  git commit -m "Merged changes from master to math/src"
  git push origin math/src
  ```

Comment: This is a great answer. But I can’t checkout only the git subtree split and push it back into the remote master. I believe this is a limitation of git. Maybe they will support this in the future…

Comment: @TamusJRoyce True, that is a missing feature for now.