# git subtree covering multiple directories

Tags: git

I'm trying to use 15 directories from the rootdir of one git repo ("FOO") in a larger project.  Changes will be made to these files in the larger project and pulled back into the "FOO" repo.  I logically want to `git subtree split --rejoin` those directories into a branch in "FOO" and then add/pull that branch up to the larger project.  Said another way, I want to keep 1-2 directories private in the "FOO" repo and not add/sync them up to the larger project.

However, when looking through the git docs and SO threads, it appears that this is not supported with `git subtree split` (see linked thread) unless I make each directory a subtree *or* I  use `git filter-branch` to rewrite the history.
[Git subtree and multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621136/git-subtree-and-multiple-directories)

Often `git filter-branch` is suggested as a solution but that appears to break any syncing back into the original "FOO" repo.  From `git filter-branch --help`: *The rewritten history will have different object names for all the objects and will not converge with the original branch* .  Any changes to the "FOO" repo structure (like putting the 15 dirs under a new dir via `filter-branch`) is not possible at this time.

Am I stuck with treating each directory as a subtree?  Doing 15 subtree splits in the larger repo (to sync back to "FOO" will take a significant amount of time.  Are there any tricks to optimizing this (e.g. 1 pass through the large repo's commits but create a branch for each folder's commits)?

Comment: One split of the larger project takes 4 minutes.  Doing all 15 subtree splits takes just under an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.44 (Q1 2024, ten years later), [batch 13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2a540e432fe5dff3cfa9d3bf7ca56db2ad12ebb9) might help.

See [commit 98ba49c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98ba49ccc247c3521659aa3d43c970e8978922c5) (01 Dec 2023) by [Zach FettersMoore (`BobaFetters`)](https://github.com/BobaFetters).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bcf5240](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bcf524023ebbc01f7706a88fa992b5680dcf0538), 02 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98ba49ccc247c3521659aa3d43c970e8978922c5): fix split processing with multiple subtrees present
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Zach FettersMoore</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Christian Couder</sup>

> When there are multiple subtrees present in a repository and they are all using git subtree split, the 'split' command can take a significant (and constantly growing) amount of time to run even when using the '--rejoin' flag.
> This is due to the fact that when processing commits to determine the last known split to start from when looking for changes, if there has been a split/merge done from another subtree there will be 2 split commits, one mainline and one subtree, for the second subtree that are part of the processing.
> The non-mainline subtree split commit will cause the processing to always need to search the entire history of the given subtree as part of its processing even though those commits are totally irrelevant to the current subtree split being run.
>
> To see this in practice you can use the open source GitHub repo 'apollo-ios-dev' and do the following in order:
>
> - Make a changes to a file in 'apollo-ios' and 'apollo-ios-codegen' directories
> - Create a commit containing these changes
> - Do a split on apollo-ios-codegen
>
>   - Do a fetch on the subtree repo
>
>     - `git fetch git@github.com:apollographql/apollo-ios-codegen.git`
>   - `git subtree split --prefix=apollo-ios-codegen --squash --rejoin`
>   - Depending on the current state of the 'apollo-ios-dev' repo you may see the issue at this point if the last split was on apollo-ios
> - Do a split on apollo-ios
>
>   - Do a fetch on the subtree repo
>
>     - `git fetch git@github.com:apollographql/apollo-ios.git`
>   - `git subtree split --prefix=apollo-ios --squash --rejoin`
> - Make changes to a file in apollo-ios-codegen
> - Create a commit containing the change(s)
> - Do a split on apollo-ios-codegen
>
>   - `git subtree split --prefix=apollo-ios-codegen --squash --rejoin`
> - To see that the patch fixes the issue you can use the custom subtree script in the repo so following the same steps as above, except instead of using `git subtree ...` for the commands use '`git-subtree.sh ...`' for the commands
>
> You will see that the final split is looking for the last split on apollo-ios-codegen to use as it's starting point to process commits.
> Since there is a split commit from apollo-ios in between the 2 splits run on apollo-ios-codegen, the processing ends up traversing the entire history of apollo-ios which increases the time it takes to do a split based on how long of a history apollo-ios has, while none of these commits are relevant to the split being done on apollo-ios-codegen.
>
> So this commit makes a change to the processing of commits for the split command in order to ignore non-mainline commits from other subtrees such as apollo-ios in the above breakdown by adding a new function '`should_ignore_subtree_commit`' which is called during '`process_split_commit`'.
> This allows the split/rejoin processing to still function as expected but removes all of the unnecessary processing that takes place currently which greatly inflates the processing time.
> In the above example, previously the final split would take ~10-12 minutes, while after this fix it takes seconds.
>
> This illustrated that when using multiple subtrees, A and B, when doing a split on subtree B, the processing does not traverse the entire history of subtree A which is unnecessary and would cause the 'extracount' of processed commits to climb based on the number of commits in the history of subtree A.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use submodules. Please read:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: If "FOO" were a submodule, I don't think it would be possible to prevent the parent repo from seeing the changesets with private directory content.