# Copy subdirectories from Git repo into a new repository (with a new directory structure)

Tags: git

This question is based on [Detach many subdirectories into a new, separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982055/detach-many-subdirectories-into-a-new-separate-git-repository)

My repository structure looks like this:

```
/apps
  /AAA
  /BBB
  /CCC
/libs
  /XXX
  /YYY
  /ZZZ
```

And I would like this instead:

```
/AAA
/XXX
```

The proposed solutions in the linked question keep the original paths of the folders. I would like instead to extract a set of folders located in different paths in a new repository, where all the folder are on root.

The other constraint, is that the commit history could involve both folders together, and I would like to preserve in the same way. For example, suppose the log in the original repository contains:

```
"My commit message"
/apps/AAA/file1.txt
/libs/XXX/file2.txt
```

I would like to see the equivalent in the new repo:

```
"My commit message"
/AAA/file1.txt
/XXX/file2.txt
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my case this way:

1) **split** the subdirs from the original repo using [git splits](https://github.com/ajdruff/git-splits) command:

```
git splits -b tmp_branch apps/AAA libs/XXX
```

2) **move** the folders to a new path using [git-mv-with-history](https://gist.github.com/emiller/6769886) command (so preserving history):

```
git checkout tmp_branch
git-mv-with-history apps/AAA/=. libs/XXX/=.
```

3) **push** the branch to a new repo

```
git push ../new_repo/ +tmp_branch:master
```

Or, if you're working on GitHub:

```
git push git@github.com:accountname/new_repo +tmp_branch:master
```

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part of this is history preservation.  It can be done with `git filter-branch`.

You almost could get by with a `subdirectory-filter`, but you could only process one directory at a time (so it would be tricky) and any commit that affected multiple of the directories would not be represented nicely in the result..

Instead you need to use a `tree-filter`, and unfortunately that means the process may take considerable time to run.  Basically the process will check out each commit (including writing the work tree), run your filter script (which will move the directories you want and remove everything else), and commit the result.  You probably want to run this on fast storage - even a RAMDisk wouldn't be overkill if there's much history at all.

Exactly what your filter script should look like depends somewhat on the environment you'll run in; but a sample filter.sh in bash might look like

```
#! /bin/bash

mv apps/AAA .
mv libs/XXX .
rm -r apps libs
```

and then you run

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter filter.sh --prune-empty
```

This creates some "backup refs" (e.g. `originals/refs/heads/master`) which you'll want to clean up.

Once those refs are removed, the original commits are still in the repo.  If you want to get rid of them, the cleanest way is to clone (using a `file://` url if doing it locally).