# Export git history, for a file and a subfolder, into another existing git repo?

Tags: git

Please consider the Bash script `testgit.sh`, pasted at the end of this post, which will reconstruct the repository examples here.

So, I have `oldrepo_git` repository, which has some files and folders - and then, a `newrepo_git` repository, which has just a single commit (for a README). This is what `gitk --all` sees in these repos:

[image: oldrepo_newrepo]

Basically, I want to export the entire git history for the file `a.txt` and the entirety of the `aa` subfolder (so, the `aa/aa.txt` and `aa/ab.txt` files - but not the `README` or `b.txt` files) from the `oldrepo_git` repository, and import it in the `newrepo_git` repository - if possible, with the right timestamps, and branching/merging info.

Since the file called `README` in `oldrepo_git` is not part of this operation, and since `newrepo_git` has nothing else but a `README` file, I wouldn't expect any conflicts to occur. However, I'm not sure what commands I can use to do this: I'm aware there is `git filter-branch`, but as far as I know, it will change the history of `oldrepo_git` "in-place" - it will not "import" this history into `newrepo_git`.

In other words, if the history of `oldrepo_git` is:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
*   7e26890 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'testbranch'
|\
| * 56ef109 (testbranch) change 5 made
| * 1a78db3 change 4 made
| * d98b4cf change 3 made
| * e5e49af change 2 made
| * 8704c24 change 1 made
|/
* f318d97 added a.txt
* 252bf7f Initial commit
```

... after the process is done, I would like to see this as the history of `newrepo_git`:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
*   XXXYYGG (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'testbranch'
|\
| * XXXYYFF (testbranch) change 5 made
| * XXXYYEE change 4 made
| * XXXYYDD change 3 made
| * XXXYYCC change 2 made
| * XXXYYBB change 1 made
|/
* XXXYYAA added a.txt
* 8e99c2d Initial commit by Bob
```

How could I perform this operation?

---

The Bash script `testgit.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rm -rf oldrepo_git newrepo_git
mkdir oldrepo_git newrepo_git

cd oldrepo_git
git init
git config user.name tester
git config user.email tester@example.com
echo "# README" >> README
git add README
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="1558960260" git commit --date "1558960260" -m "Initial commit"
echo "Testing" >> a.txt
git add a.txt
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="1558960270" git commit --date "1558960270" -m "added a.txt"
git checkout -b testbranch
mkdir aa bb
for ix in 1 2 3 4 5; do
  echo $ix >> a.txt
  echo $ix >> b.txt
  echo $ix >> aa/aa.txt
  echo $ix >> aa/ab.txt
  git add .
  newts="$((1558960270+ix*10))"
  GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$newts" git commit --date "$newts" -m "change $ix made"
done
git checkout master
ix="$((ix+1))"; newts="$((1558960270+ix*10))"
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$newts" GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$newts" git merge --no-ff --no-edit testbranch

cd ../newrepo_git
git init
git config user.name bob
git config user.email bob@example.com
echo "# Bob's README" >> README
git add README
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="1558960260" git commit --date "1558960260" -m "Initial commit by Bob"
```

Comment: Are there files in `oldrepo_git` you don't want to transfer over? If not, I would be inclined to merge in the actual history from `oldrepo_git` into `newrepo_git`, which you can do by adding both remote in one sandbox and doing a regular merge.

Comment: Thanks @joanis - indeed, there are files I do not want to transfer "*... not the README or b.txt files*" (and I intended to not want anything in the folder `bb/` either, but I pasted the wrong example, so there is nothing in `bb/` if you run the OP example as it is, anyway) - which is why I thought a regular "add remote, then fetch" approach would not work.

Comment: OK, I guess I should have read the question more carefully. Then you want to look into tools that rewrite history with some files removed - search for how to get rid of large files in a repo, there are plenty of questions about that in SO - and then merging the result in might be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: you may want to add an extra `echo $ix >> bb/bb.txt` in the `for` loop in the `testgit.sh` script in OP, so that the output in this post matches.

---

Ok, I guess this is how it should be done - at least in relation to the OP (where we don't have remote repos yet); first, copy the oldrepo:

```
cp -a oldrepo_git oldrepo_filt_git
```

Then apparently we have to delete all the stuff we don't want in the copied oldrepo, by using `git filter-branch` in combination with `git rm` - part of this command I found here: [Detach many subdirectories into a new, separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982055/detach-many-subdirectories-into-a-new-separate-git-repository/7849648)

```
cd oldrepo_filt_git
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r $(bash -O extglob -c 'ls -xd !(a*)')" --prune-empty -- --all
```

Note, since here we want to tell to `git rm` what to delete, we want to specify what we do not want to keep, as the inverse of what we want to keep; and here I want to keep `a.txt` file and `aa` folder - so a glob match would be `a*`. Then you need the `bash` extglob function to get that; so if a whole list is:

```
$ ls
a.txt  aa  b.txt  bb  README
```

... then the extglob stanza which will give us only the file/folder names to delete gives:

```
$ bash -O extglob -c 'ls -xd !(a*)'
b.txt  bb  README
```

So, after `git filter-branch` command is ran:

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r $(bash -O extglob -c 'ls -xd !(a*)')" --prune-empty -- --all
Rewrite 252bf7ff5f385dad880240d5d80e68f24ae09b59 (1/8) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    rm 'README'
Rewrite f318d9712cd7aacdb5dd45febbcdbbce6b741e08 (2/8) (1 seconds passed, remaining 3 predicted)    rm 'README'
Rewrite 00b62e7da8784d45850d7483cbea88fdc4aa844c (2/8) (1 seconds passed, remaining 3 predicted)    rm 'README'
rm 'b.txt'
rm 'bb/bb.txt'
Rewrite c618eff47d38412c54a8381a5bacc921bddefe2d (2/8) (1 seconds passed, remaining 3 predicted)    rm 'README'
rm 'b.txt'
rm 'bb/bb.txt'
Rewrite 2cada8d822d83f37bdc4a37bcfb03047c1cc1ded (5/8) (3 seconds passed, remaining 1 predicted)    rm 'README'
rm 'b.txt'
rm 'bb/bb.txt'
Rewrite 7b296b70018f4105f190d06ed4d9c58e3f80532f (5/8) (3 seconds passed, remaining 1 predicted)    rm 'README'
rm 'b.txt'
rm 'bb/bb.txt'
Rewrite 18a1ad1d35cd8573c39485d0a29b630325f9727d (7/8) (5 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    rm 'README'
rm 'b.txt'
rm 'bb/bb.txt'
Rewrite 2ffbbf03d51363f1ced3aaaf000d5921c9d8b919 (7/8) (5 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    rm 'README'
rm 'b.txt'
rm 'bb/bb.txt'

Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/heads/testbranch' was rewritten
```

... we have:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --stat
*   31cd8b5 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'testbranch'
|\
| * 42b153d (testbranch) change 5 made
| |  a.txt     | 1 +
| |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| * ff1be9d change 4 made
| |  a.txt     | 1 +
| |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| * 90f050c change 3 made
| |  a.txt     | 1 +
| |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| * d2d2136 change 2 made
| |  a.txt     | 1 +
| |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| * ab237ac change 1 made
|/
|    a.txt     | 1 +
|    aa/aa.txt | 1 +
|    aa/ab.txt | 1 +
|    3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
* ea0a32d added a.txt
   a.txt | 1 +
   1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

... which confirms that this is the filtered state of the repository that I wanted - and I guess, this I'd want to merge into my `newrepo_git` now.

---

Ok, so it turns out, I don't quite want to "merge" into `newrepo_git`, I want to "join" - most of the info for here I found in [Join two Git repositories and keep the original commit dates. - axiac@web](http://axiac.ro/blog/merging-git-repositories/)

So, first, we change directory to newrepo:

```
cd ../newrepo_git
```

Note that at this point, most of the resources online will recommend:

```
git remote add oldrepo ../oldrepo_filt_git/
git pull oldrepo master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

... but this will result with a history with two roots - which is not what I want:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --stat
*   845c81e (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'master' of ../oldrepo_filt_git
|\
| *   31cd8b5 (oldrepo/master) Merge branch 'testbranch'
| |\
| | * 42b153d (oldrepo/testbranch) change 5 made
| | |  a.txt     | 1 +
| | |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| | |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| | |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| | * ff1be9d change 4 made
| | |  a.txt     | 1 +
| | |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| | |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| | |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| | * 90f050c change 3 made
| | |  a.txt     | 1 +
| | |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| | |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| | |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| | * d2d2136 change 2 made
| | |  a.txt     | 1 +
| | |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| | |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| | |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| | * ab237ac change 1 made
| |/
| |    a.txt     | 1 +
| |    aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| |    aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| |    3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| * ea0a32d added a.txt
|    a.txt | 1 +
|    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
* 8e99c2d Initial commit by Bob
   README | 1 +
   1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

What I want, instead, is that commit `ea0a32d added a.txt` follows/stems from `8e99c2d Initial commit by Bob` -> that would be the "joining" of repositories mentioned earlier.

Note also, you could do `git format-patch --root HEAD -o ../` from `oldrepo_git`, and then import the patches in `newrepo_git` with `for ix in ../*.patch; do echo $ix; git am -k < $ix; done` - but this will *not* preserve merge history (all history will be flattened)!

So, in order to do a proper "joining", instead, I do first a fetch:

```
$ git remote add old-repo ../oldrepo_filt_git

$ git fetch old-repo
warning: no common commits
remote: Enumerating objects: 29, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (29/29), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
remote: Total 29 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (29/29), done.
From ../oldrepo_filt_git
 * [new branch]      master     -> old-repo/master
 * [new branch]      testbranch -> old-repo/testbranch
```

... then adding and renaming of branches, (and saving of timestamps in `/tmp/hashlist`) as recommended in the post - and then cherry-pick the first commit in old-repo:

```
$ git branch oldrepo-head old-repo/master
Branch 'oldrepo-head' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'old-repo'.

$ git branch oldrepo-root $(git log oldrepo-head --reverse --pretty=%H | head -n 1)

$ git log --pretty='%T %ct' ..oldrepo-head > /tmp/hashlist

$ git branch -m master new-master

$ git cherry-pick --strategy-option=theirs oldrepo-root
[new-master 427cf77] added a.txt
 Author: tester <tester@example.com>
 Date: Mon May 27 14:31:10 2019 +0200
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
```

At this point, the repo state is:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
* 427cf77 (HEAD -> new-master) added a.txt
* 8e99c2d Initial commit by Bob
```

Now, here we can do a rebase - note that in the cited post, they get an error here, but for this particular example, it seems to proceed without an error:

```
$ git rebase --preserve-merges --onto new-master --root oldrepo-head
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/oldrepo-head.
```

At this point, the newrepo history is *almost* there - the only problem is that the commit timestamps are different:

```
$ git log --graph --pretty=fuller
*   commit 61fbe54721a9432e91e48917ed036f55da4105a4 (HEAD -> oldrepo-head)
|\  Merge: 427cf77 f8e8f8a
| | Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| | AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:32:10 2019 +0200
| | Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| | CommitDate: Tue May 28 12:57:00 2019 +0200
| |
| |     Merge branch 'testbranch'
| |
| * commit f8e8f8aedaa7bc999bdfdd49542c9ee04edb770c
| | Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| | AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:32:00 2019 +0200
| | Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| | CommitDate: Tue May 28 12:56:58 2019 +0200
| |
| |     change 5 made
| |
| * commit b084029040d6596e0795e7567b2684dc59c02241
| | Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| | AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:50 2019 +0200
| | Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| | CommitDate: Tue May 28 12:56:56 2019 +0200
| |
| |     change 4 made
| |
| * commit b62dabca3a46efbe76edb10591935db136f74aaa
| | Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| | AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:40 2019 +0200
| | Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| | CommitDate: Tue May 28 12:56:54 2019 +0200
| |
| |     change 3 made
| |
| * commit 252f3e9697b87b4f59cd0a74681ef25401340fcf
| | Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| | AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:30 2019 +0200
| | Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| | CommitDate: Tue May 28 12:56:51 2019 +0200
| |
| |     change 2 made
| |
| * commit c382c8a713489ca0e5dc106bed29fdce379952b0
|/  Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
|   AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:20 2019 +0200
|   Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
|   CommitDate: Tue May 28 12:56:49 2019 +0200
|
|       change 1 made
|
* commit 427cf77417a2406db5dd6a0e9bd4fb60542f2ee1 (new-master)
| Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:10 2019 +0200
| Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| CommitDate: Tue May 28 12:55:43 2019 +0200
|
|     added a.txt
|
* commit 8e99c2d71048b4999d012b33d34386351d6d0fef
  Author:     bob <bob@example.com>
  AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:00 2019 +0200
  Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
  CommitDate: Mon May 27 14:31:00 2019 +0200

      Initial commit by Bob
```

They have the same problem in the cited post, too, and the suggestion is to use `filter-branch` to rewrite the commit timestamps, to be the same as the author timestamps:

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter 'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(fgrep -m 1 $(git log -1 --pretty=%T $GIT_COMMIT) /tmp/hashlist | cut -d" " -f2)' new-master..oldrepo-head
Rewrite 61fbe54721a9432e91e48917ed036f55da4105a4 (3/6) (1 seconds passed, remaining 1 predicted)
Ref 'refs/heads/oldrepo-head' was rewritten
```

... however, this did not work for me, because by now, the commit hashes have changed from what was there in `/tmp/hashlist`.

So, I used an easier approach - simply have `filter-branch` read the author date timestamp at each commit, and copy/reapply it as committer date (note I use `-f` here to compensate for the effects of the previous `filter-branch`, otherwise I get "Cannot create a new backup. ... Force overwriting the backup with -f"):

```
$ git filter-branch -f --env-filter 'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(git log -1 --pretty=%at $GIT_COMMIT)' new-master..oldrepo-head
Rewrite f2b2385d85c74dbf0cbf8fabc02ec30cb50d8f2a (3/6) (1 seconds passed, remaining 1 predicted)
Ref 'refs/heads/oldrepo-head' was rewritten
```

At this point, we can see that the state of the repo is *almost* as I need it - except the first oldrepo commit does not have the commit timestamp changed; so I try again:

```
sd@DESKTOP-RO11QOC MSYS /c/Users/sd/AppData/Local/Temp/newrepo_git
$ git filter-branch -f --env-filter 'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(git log -1 --pretty=%at $GIT_COMMIT)' 427cf77417a
You must specify a ref to rewrite.

sd@DESKTOP-RO11QOC MSYS /c/Users/sd/AppData/Local/Temp/newrepo_git
$ git filter-branch -f --env-filter 'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(git log -1 --pretty=%at $GIT_COMMIT)' new-master
Rewrite 427cf77417a2406db5dd6a0e9bd4fb60542f2ee1 (2/2) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
Ref 'refs/heads/new-master' was rewritten
```

... but it still shows the same difference between timestamps in log:

```
$ git log --graph --stat --pretty=fuller
*   commit cdaa4b82f3833770a9051a2490487548603e3af8 (HEAD -> oldrepo-head)
|\  Merge: 427cf77 9bfc6cd
| | Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| | AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:32:10 2019 +0200
| | Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| | CommitDate: Mon May 27 14:32:10 2019 +0200
| |
| |     Merge branch 'testbranch'
| |
...
* commit 427cf77417a2406db5dd6a0e9bd4fb60542f2ee1 (refs/original/refs/heads/new-master)
| Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:10 2019 +0200
| Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| CommitDate: Tue May 28 12:55:43 2019 +0200
|
|     added a.txt
|
|  a.txt | 1 +
|  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
...
```

Anyways, now we should "cleanup" as recommended in the post:

```
$ git branch -m oldrepo-head master
$ git branch -D oldrepo-root
Deleted branch oldrepo-root (was ea0a32d).
$ git branch -D new-master
Deleted branch new-master (was 4ac225e).
$ rm .git/refs/original/refs/heads/new-master
$ git remote remove old-repo
```

And finally, I managed to overwrite the commit timestamp for commit 427cf774, by adding a temporary branch there (since filter-branch needs a ref, it seemingly cannot use a commit hash directly), and using it to specify `tmp^..tmp` as the filter-branch range:

```
$ git branch tmp 427cf774
$ git filter-branch -f --env-filter 'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(git log -1 --pretty=%at $GIT_COMMIT)' tmp^..tmp
Rewrite 427cf77417a2406db5dd6a0e9bd4fb60542f2ee1 (1/1) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
Ref 'refs/heads/tmp' was rewritten
$ git log --graph --stat --pretty=fuller tmp
* commit 4ac225e308e280e3a96be0168c6e9dece44d4979 (tmp)
| Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:10 2019 +0200
| Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| CommitDate: Mon May 27 14:31:10 2019 +0200
|
|     added a.txt
|
|  a.txt | 1 +
|  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
|
...
$ git branch -D tmp
Deleted branch tmp (was 4ac225e).
```

... and finally, I can see that newrepo contains oldrepo commits as I envisioned them:

```
$ git log --graph --stat --pretty=fuller
*   commit cdaa4b82f3833770a9051a2490487548603e3af8
|\  Merge: 427cf77 9bfc6cd
| | Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| | AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:32:10 2019 +0200
| | Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| | CommitDate: Mon May 27 14:32:10 2019 +0200
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'testbranch'
| | 
| * commit 9bfc6cde58be9102102f839e5cc0fe8f25f0f78c
| | Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| | AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:32:00 2019 +0200
| | Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| | CommitDate: Mon May 27 14:32:00 2019 +0200
| | 
| |     change 5 made
| | 
| |  a.txt     | 1 +
| |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| | 
| * commit 485ae0f50054610b6a41098fb695e59d194cc856
| | Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| | AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:50 2019 +0200
| | Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| | CommitDate: Mon May 27 14:31:50 2019 +0200
| | 
| |     change 4 made
| | 
| |  a.txt     | 1 +
| |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| | 
| * commit b6804b6e8e313b5c4766568a287f0785503e3a11
| | Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| | AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:40 2019 +0200
| | Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| | CommitDate: Mon May 27 14:31:40 2019 +0200
| | 
| |     change 3 made
| | 
| |  a.txt     | 1 +
| |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| | 
| * commit 8b463423d2a99929a6a248e38ba1368a56d3769d
| | Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| | AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:30 2019 +0200
| | Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| | CommitDate: Mon May 27 14:31:30 2019 +0200
| | 
| |     change 2 made
| | 
| |  a.txt     | 1 +
| |  aa/aa.txt | 1 +
| |  aa/ab.txt | 1 +
| |  3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| | 
| * commit 3bc0bed30ebea1498a15711825b2ea8347cc374d
|/  Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
|   AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:20 2019 +0200
|   Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
|   CommitDate: Mon May 27 14:31:20 2019 +0200
|   
|       change 1 made
|   
|    a.txt     | 1 +
|    aa/aa.txt | 1 +
|    aa/ab.txt | 1 +
|    3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
| 
* commit 427cf77417a2406db5dd6a0e9bd4fb60542f2ee1
| Author:     tester <tester@example.com>
| AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:10 2019 +0200
| Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
| CommitDate: Tue May 28 12:55:43 2019 +0200
| 
|     added a.txt
| 
|  a.txt | 1 +
|  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
| 
* commit 8e99c2d71048b4999d012b33d34386351d6d0fef
  Author:     bob <bob@example.com>
  AuthorDate: Mon May 27 14:31:00 2019 +0200
  Commit:     bob <bob@example.com>
  CommitDate: Mon May 27 14:31:00 2019 +0200

      Initial commit by Bob

   README | 1 +
   1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Easy, eh? `:)`

---

But I'm not really sure if this is the right process - so if anyone more knowledgeable can confirm it - or if there is an easier way, - that would be great ...