# Proper way to remove unwanted files with git filter-branch without git rm failing

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a project of an SNMP agent where the related MIB files (*.smiv2 files) were developed along with it, but now I want them in a separate git repository.

In order not to lose any of the MIB files history, since they didn't start in the same directory they are now, I couldn't just use `--subdirectory-filter` filter-branch, so I tried the `--filter-index` approach, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998987/splitting-a-set-of-files-within-a-git-repo-into-their-own-repository-preserving). The idea would be to remove every file which doesn't end with `.smiv2` (obviously on a fresh clone of the original project, which shall be pushed to my new MIBs repo by the end of the process).

To make it simpler, I chose using `ls-files` over `ls-tree`, so instead of:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git ls-tree -r --name-only \
--full-tree $GIT_COMMIT | grep -v ".smiv2$" | xargs git rm --cached \
--ignore-unmatch -r'
```

I used this:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git ls-files | \
grep -v ".smiv2$" | xargs git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch'
```

but any of these failed in the first commit, since it appears `git rm` was fed no arguments at all (I suppose `--ignore-unmatch` will work fine if the supplied arguments are not found, but not in the case no arguments are supplied):

```
$ git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git ls-files | \
>     grep -v ".smiv2$" | xargs git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch'
Rewrite 4cd2f1c98dbaa96bc103ae81fbd405bd1d991d9a (1/418)usage: git rm [options] [--] <file>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -q, --quiet           do not list removed files
    --cached              only remove from the index
    -f, --force           override the up-to-date check
    -r                    allow recursive removal
    --ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched

index filter failed: git ls-files | \
    grep -v ".smiv2$" | xargs git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch
```

I got it working wrapping `git rm` in a script which returns success even when it fails due to lack of arguments (saved it in `/usr/local/bin/gitrm_alt`):

```
#!/bin/sh
git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch "$@" 
exit 0
```

and then calling that instead of `git rm`:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git ls-files | \
    grep -v ".smiv2$" | xargs gitrm_alt'
```

but I found that extremely ugly and clunky, so I'd like to ask if there's a more direct/proper way to do this.

Comment: Why not pass an extra dummy argument that never exists to `git rm --ignore-unmatched`, e.g. `| xargs rm --cached --ignore-unmatched DoesNotExistInMyProject`?

Comment: hehe.. perfect @CharlesBailey, how couldn't I see that? Don't you want to turn that into an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add a dummy argument to `git rm` so that it always has at least one file parameter.

E.g.

```
... | xargs git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch DoesNotExistInMyProject
```

Answer (score 5):

`xargs`'s `-r`|`--no-run-if-empty` flag might be cleaner:

> `... | xargs`**`--no-run-if-empty`**`git rm --cached --ignore-unmatched`

Answer (score 3):

Full Answer, for future reference

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git ls-files | \
grep -v ".smiv2$" | xargs git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch DoesNotExistInMyProject'
```

Answer (score 0):

An -I switch can also be used.

```
some command | xargs -I % rm %
```