# git remove all deleted files from entire history

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

I was wondering if anybody has a more efficient, more intelligent way to do this. The looping construct requires every deleted files to be expunged from every commit by reading each commit. With many commits, this takes a long time.

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-status | grep -i ^D | cut -f2- | sort -u | xargs -I {} git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch {}' HEAD
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems to remove each files one at a time.
Consider that [`git rm`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) can take multiple files to be removed.

So one optimization would be to build that list and call the filter-branch once.
You can see one example of that approach in "[Proper way to remove unwanted files with `git filter-branch` without `git rm` failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179611/proper-way-to-remove-unwanted-files-with-git-filter-branch-without-git-rm-failin)".

Comment: I've found `grep -v -x -f /tmp/files-in-repo.txt` along with `xargs --delimiter=\\n -r git rm ... ` useful.

Answer (score 4):

Just a small improvement to support recursive delete

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git log --pretty=format: --name-status | grep -i ^D | cut -f2- | sort -u | xargs git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch DoesNotExistInMyProject'
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who might be looking for the same answer, I modified the original command above with the suggestions linked in [the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179611/proper-way-to-remove-unwanted-files-with-git-filter-branch-without-git-rm-failin) and created this command which seemed to work for me.

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git log --pretty=format: --name-status | grep -i ^D | cut -f2- | sort -u | xargs git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch DoesNotExistInMyProject'
```

Answer (score 1):

Improved the command to avoid file names with a ' which causes xargs to bug

`echo "/!\ This file contains a single quote ' and it's gonna bug with xargs, so it's excluded from the filter operation" ; bash -c "git log --pretty=format: --name-status | grep -i ^D " | grep \' 
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --index-filter "git log --pretty=format: --name-status | grep -i ^D | grep -v \' | cut -f2- | sort -u | xargs git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch DoesNotExistInMyProject"`