# Git extract folder from submodule with history

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm moving code around at work, and I'm stuck on a particular problem. I have the following architecture :

```
repo
|- submodule A
|   |- folder A1
|   |- folder A2
|- folder B
    |- folder B1
```

And I want to move `folder A2` into `folder B` with the complete history, to end up with this :

```
repo
|- submodule A
|   |- folder A1
|- folder B
    |- folder B1
    |- folder A2
```

It seems that `git filter-branch` could do the tricks, but I can't find any example about this particular problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move a single directory from a git repository to a new repository whilst maintaining the history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811251/how-can-i-move-a-single-directory-from-a-git-repository-to-a-new-repository-whil)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/28583470/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1662753/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/q/28830916/7976758