# How should I save one single file updated log when I move one file to another git repo?

Tags: git

I have read [How to move files from one git repo to another (not a clone), preserving history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history)

My dir:

```
➜  website git:(master) tree
.
├── README.md
├── sub-dir-1
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── sub-dir-2
│   └── file3
```

I can move `sub-dir-1` to another repo and save its git history log.

But I want to move `README.md` to another repo which save git history log, because `README.md` is old repo root file which isn't sub dir.

So, how should I do? thanks!

EDIT: solved according to [Splitting a set of files within a git repo into their own repository, preserving relevant history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998987/splitting-a-set-of-files-within-a-git-repo-into-their-own-repository-preserving)

Comment: The funny thing is a directory doesn't have history. The repo itself _is_ the history. In my mind you could fork the repo and then make changes to it, but I don't think it's possible to extract a folder and keep "it's history".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a set of files within a git repo into their own repository, preserving relevant history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998987/splitting-a-set-of-files-within-a-git-repo-into-their-own-repository-preserving)