# git-filter-branch with --index-filter : strange bash error ( ! : event not found)

Tags: git, bash, git-filter-branch

I am using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982055/detach-many-subdirectories-into-a-new-separate-git-repository) to strip a clone of a repository to a list of files I want to keep in a spin off of this project. Say I want to strip all but directory `src/main` and its sub-directories. Because I will have multiple files and directories, I use `--index-filter` instead of `--subdirectory-filter`.

I thought the following should work:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -r -f --cached --ignore-unmatch ↩
  src/!(main)" --prune-empty -- --all
```

But all I get is

```
-bash: !: event not found
```

I tried all sorts of different paths instead of `src/!(main)`. I always get exactly that error message. It seems to be a bash problem, because that line also doesn't enter my command line history?

---

That is to say, if I have top level files `A`, and `B`, and subdirectory `C/D`, how can I remove **all but** these three things?

Comment: In the meantime, I have success by giving `gm rm` a list of all files to __remove__, instead of specifying the ones to __keep__. Quite a pain in this case because there are many compared to the few I want to keep; but it seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ! is the issue, since it is used for command history recall.  Inside quotes, putting a backslash in front does not help either, so the `\!`  must be outside quotes.  Can be illustrated using a few examples with echo:

```
/home/user1> echo "src/!(main)"
-bash: !: event not found
/home/user1> echo "src/\!(main)"
src/\!(main)
/home/user1> echo "src/"\!"(main)"
src/!(main)
```

Comment: It's meant to be an *extglob* matching everything in `src` but `main`.

Comment: @kynan:  globbing (including extglob) does not work inside quotes.  Are you attempting to use an extglob pattern for filename expansion?

Comment: That's what the OP was intending: have a look at the question clarification and my answer for how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the the actual question added in the clarification: you're trying to use bash's *extglob* to remove everything in `src` but `main` in a `git index-filter`. This doesn't work because the index-filter command is *not* executed by your shell, but by `sh` via `eval` (see `/usr/lib/git-core/git-filter-branch:327`).

[You can't tell git to enable *extglob* when doing this, but you can make your shell expand the *extglob* before passing it to `index-filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079852/396967):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -r -f --cached --ignore-unmatch $(ls -xd src/!(main))" --prune-empty -- --all
```

Comment: /usr/local/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch for me on OSX

Comment: @JamesEJ That means git is not on your `$PATH`

Comment: I meant to see the source, was incredibly useful!

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation point is used in Bash's syntax to do [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction), which is what causes the confusion. You must escape it using backslash or single quotes:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -r -f --cached --ignore-unmatch ↩
  src/\!(main)" --prune-empty -- --all
```

Comment: Hmmm. That just gives me `syntax error near unexpected token '('` - `eval: line 349: 'git rm -r -f --cached --ignore-unmatch src/\!(main)'`

Comment: Unfortunately, when used inside quotes, the \ is retained.